# Should you pass in block variables even if they aren't used?

Tags: ruby

Using HackerRank to brush up on my skills, and saw this piece of code:

```
> h = {1 => 1, 2 => 4, 3 => 9, 4 => 16, 5 => 25}
 => {1 => 1, 2 => 4, 3 => 9, 4 => 16, 5 => 25}
> h.keep_if {|key, value| key % 2 == 0}
```

I saw that even though the `value` block variable was not used, it was still passed in. I know that it works either way (with or without `value`), but is it more correct to pass in variables that you don't plan on using? Or to pass in variables that even though aren't used, should still be passed in, because it's considered better "form".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably opinionated but the rule in the projects I work on is to pass it in but only as a `_value` or `_` as it communicates at the definition of the block that the variable was not forgotten but will not be used.

So in your example this would mean

```
h.keep_if {|key, _| key % 2 == 0}
```

We usually enforce it via rubocop using [RuboCop::Cop::Lint::UnusedMethodArgument](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/UnusedMethodArgument)

That same rule is applied when a method is overridden and the overriding implementation does not make use of a variable but needs to list it in order to match the original signature.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that `_` and `_a` are valid local variables. One could write, for example, `[1,2,3].map { |_| 2*_ } #=> [2, 4, 6]`. Block variables whose names begin with an underscore are special in one respect, however: `[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]].map { |_y  ,x, _y| x } #=> [2, 4]`, whereas `[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]].map { |y, x, y| x } #=> SyntaxError: (irb):569: duplicated argument name`.

Answer (score -1):

I realized after testing it out in IRB, that is mandatory to pass in the `value` variable in certain methods to make them work.

```
hash = {1=>3, 4=>7, 3=>2, 5=>6}
hash.find{|k|k.odd?} #without value block variable will return an error
hash.find{|k,v|k.odd?} #returns [1,3]
```

Comment: `hash.find{|k| puts "k=#{k}"; k.odd?} #=> k=[1, 3] NoMethodError: undefined method 'odd?' for [1, 3]:Array`. The first value passed to the block is `hash.find.next #=> [1, 3]` The block variable `k` is then set equal to that array. Incidentally, this is not an answer, so you should remove it. You could add it to your question, however.